# Delete Excel Rows

Tags: c#

I can delete my worksheets in my workbook, in c# windows application.
But How to Delete my excel sheet selected Rows with C# Windows?

```
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false; 
        string filePath = @"d:\test.xlsx";
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        Excel.Sheets worksheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
        worksheets[1].Delete();
        xlWorkBook.Save();
        xlWorkBook.Close();

        releaseObject(worksheets);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Worksheet Deleted!");


It will usefull to bets outputs:
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a reference to the worksheet say

```
for(int i = 1; i <=100; i++)
{
  if(!worksheet.Cells[i,1].Contains("SomeString"))
  {
     ((Range)worksheet.Rows[i]).Delete(shiftDirection)
  }
}
```

where shiftDirection see here: [Range.Delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.delete.aspx)

You may have to cast the Cell's content to a string.

Answer (score 1):

I am expecting you want to delete the row in excel in C#

If you are using microsoft Interlop services to read and write Excel file....
Then,
Here is the process wherein you'll have to assign the range(row which you want to delete)

```
Excel.Range range = worksheets.get_Range("A3","A20".ToString());
//setting the range for deleting the rows

range.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
//for deleting the rows; in case of columns use: 'EntireColumn' instead of 'EntireRow'

xlWorkBook.Save();
//save the workbook

xlWorkBook.Close(false, "", false);
//close the workbook

xlApp.Quit();
//quit the workbook
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: happy to help :-), meanwhile up-vote or select tick my ans if its apt for your issue.